# Kubernetes Kubeconfig for admin credentials generated by Kops

Tags: kubernetes, kops

How we can re-generate kubeconfig file of the admin user generated by Kops? This in the case we have many users using it and we decide to create a different privileged access to cluster resources using the RBAC concept. We have created users for each privilege access and this works fine, but need to make sure that the kubeconfig, which contains the admin credentials, is not used by any user any more.

NOTE: We have changed the base64 encoding in the s3 bucket under /cluster_name/secrets/admin then kops rolling-update for the cluster but nothing has been changed.

Comment: Are you using x509 certificate authentication for the `cluster-admin` credentials that "leaked" out, or a JWT, or a static password? (I have a theory, but thought I'd check before spouting off based on my theory)

Comment: yes it is "x509" certificate authentication

Comment: Then you're going to have to rotate the CA used to sign those credentials, as there is no other path forward that I know of; that also means you'll have to rotate the serviceAccount credentials injected into **every** Pod, which thankfully is almost automatic by just deleting the service account `Secret` in every namespace, but you'll have to bounce every Pod in order for them to pick up the new Secret binding. It's a monster PITA

Comment: Right now this feature is available https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/operations/rotate-secrets/, however after I rotate the keypair `kubecfg` is not rotated. If I try creating a new keypair, it throws this error: `Error: adding keypair to "kubecfg" is not supported`. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you cannot revoke certificate for now https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60917.

Issue is still open on github https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18982